# Snowflake won't use materialized view if I join tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, materialized-views

I'm trying to join my fact table to my dim table. A Materialized view has been created on my fact table to help with performance when getting the sum of totals. However, I'm seeing that my MV isn't being used in example #1. The only time it works is if I created an aggregated sub-query based on examples #2

The examples below use data from Snowflake's sample data.

Do I always have to write my query like example #2 to make use of it?

```
--creating the MV
create or replace materialized view my_db.public.inventory_mv as 
(select inv_item_sk,sum(INV_QUANTITY_ON_HAND) as INV_QUANTITY_ON_HAND from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF10TCL"."INVENTORY" group by 1)
```

```
--Example #1 - My MV does not get used according to the query plan
select 
    b.I_PRODUCT_NAME
    ,sum(a.INV_QUANTITY_ON_HAND) INV_QUANTITY_ON_HAND
from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF10TCL"."INVENTORY" a
join "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF10TCL"."ITEM" b on a.inv_item_sk = b.i_item_sk 
group by 1
```

```
--Example #2 - The query planner indicates MV is used
select 
    b.I_PRODUCT_NAME
    ,sum(a.INV_QUANTITY_ON_HAND) INV_QUANTITY_ON_HAND
from (select inv_item_sk,sum(INV_QUANTITY_ON_HAND) as INV_QUANTITY_ON_HAND from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF10TCL"."INVENTORY" group by 1) a
join "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF10TCL"."ITEM" b on a.inv_item_sk = b.i_item_sk 
group by 1
```

Comment: The Snowflake query optimiser will determine whether or not using the MV or the underlying base table is more performant - just because there is an MV available doesn’t mean it will get used

Comment: @NickW I understand that however based on the query profile its clear as night and day that the making use of the MV is much more optimal in terms of speed, bytes scanned, and total partitions.

Comment: @user3016699 Snowflake never guarantee that the MV will always be used in each and every use cases where it can be helpful. In this case, I would just reference the MV directly having proved that it would provide better performance overall. But thanks for bringing this up, hope that the optimizer will be more reliable in MV usage

Answer (score 0):

Even if a materialized view can replace the base table in a particular query, the optimizer might not use the materialized view. For example, if the base table is clustered by a field, the optimizer might choose to scan the base table (rather than the materialized view) because the optimizer can effectively prune out partitions and provide equivalent performance using the base table.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#how-the-query-optimizer-uses-materialized-views

Answer (score 0):

It's not using the MV because the MV and query are grouping by a different column.

```
--creating the MV
create or replace materialized view my_db.public.inventory_mv as 
(select inv_item_sk ... group by 1)
```

The MV definition is grouping by `inv_item_sk`.

```
--Example #1 - My MV does not get used according to the query plan
select 
    b.I_PRODUCT_NAME ...
group by 1
```

The query is grouping by `I_PRODUCT_NAME`.

Since the MV and query are grouping by different columns, the optimizer will not use the MV. In the second example the MV is used in the FROM clause, so it has to be used.

Comment: Good to know. IMO that seems to defeat the purpose of how a MV should be used. When using fact and dim tables in my BI tool, I'm not going to be writing custom sql to aggregate my data as that should be handled in the BI layer. I guess the only way to get around this is if snowflake supported the ability to joins in a MV